# Plot events occurred within specific duration

Tags: sql, ms-access

Want to plot B and C in sperate column based on A, if B or C reported within +-  15 min duration of A.

Table SD
Event_ID    Event Type  Event_Time
XX-704  A   2018-07-17 21:06
XX-704  B   2018-07-17 21:06
XX-704  C   2018-07-17 21:09
XX-704  A   2018-07-18 15:08
XX-704  B   2018-07-18 15:09
XX-704  C   2018-07-18 19:07
XX-991  B   2018-07-18 11:41
XX-991  C   2018-07-18 11:42
XX-991  C   2018-07-18 11:43
XX-262  A   2018-07-18 14:23
XX-262  B   2018-07-18 14:09
XX-262  C   2018-07-18 15:08

Expected Result
Event_ID    A   B   C
XX-704  2018-07-17 21:06    2018-07-17 21:06    2018-07-17 21:09
XX-704  2018-07-18 15:08    2018-07-18 15:09
XX-991  2018-07-18 11:41    2018-07-18 11:41    2018-07-18 11:42
XX-262  2018-07-18 14:23    2018-07-18 14:09

Created sperate tables for A B C .
I was trying datediff ('n',a.down_time,b.down_time) <= 15 and datediff ('n',a.down_time,b.down_time) >= -15

But  it was throwing syntax error

Comment: This is a good resource for improving your SQL questions.  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Sample Data and Expected Result in well formatted text (no images) are very important.

Comment: What to display if there are multiple B and C events in the 15 minutes interval after an A event? Which B event should be displayed next to which C event and why?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . `exists` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t as t
where exists (select 1
              from t as t2
              where abs(datediff("n", t.down_time, t2.down_time)) <= 15 and
                    t2.event = "A"
             );
```